# How to Write a rewrite rule in my sub directory htaccess file to achieve this

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have a sub directory named as "apps" under my public html folder.I fetch "apps" database table records and show some of the records on index.php file and give a link to another file to show more records for the particular row.
I have another file named "details.php" in the same directory where i show full records of selected row.

my link looks like this

```
<a href="details.php?
name=APP_NAME">APP NAME 
</a>
```

where APP_NAME is unique in database table.

suppose i have an app named "oreo" in my db
then the link look like

```
<a href="details.php?
name=oreo">oreo 
</a>
```

I want rewrite this url to make it seo friendly like this

```
<a href="oreo">oreo 
</a>
```

and full url will look like this

```
https://example.com/apps/oreo
```

I have tried this code,but it's not working

```
RewriteRule ^/apps/(.*)$ 
/details.php?name=$1
```

I don't have much clarity on Rewrite Rule..So I need help..

Answer (score 0):

got it.It works

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /apps/details.php?name=$1
```